# How to overcome 'TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null' error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, bots

I am trying to build a bot. So in one Node.js file, I am getting the following error while using `ActivityHandler`-
`TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`

Here is the code which I am using -

```
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');
const { LuisRecognizer, QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');

class DispatchBot extends ActivityHandler {

    constructor(logger) {
        super();
        if (!logger) {
            logger = console;
            logger.log('[DispatchBot]: logger not passed in, defaulting to console');
        }

        const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
            applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
            endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
            endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`
        }, {
            includeAllIntents: true,
            includeInstanceData: true
        }, true);

        const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
            knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
            endpointKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
            host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
        });

        this.logger = logger;
        this.dispatchRecognizer = dispatchRecognizer;
        this.qnaMaker = qnaMaker;

        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            this.logger.log('Processing Message Activity.');

            const recognizerResult = await dispatchRecognizer.recognize(context);

            const intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(recognizerResult);

            await this.dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult);

            await next();
        });

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const welcomeText = 'Type a greeting or a question about the weather to get started.';
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;

            for (let member of membersAdded) {
                if (member.id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    await context.sendActivity(`Welcome to Dispatch bot ${ member.name }. ${ welcomeText }`);
                }
            }

            await next();
        });
    }

    async dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult) {
        switch (intent) {
        case 'l_luis':
            await this.processLuis(context, recognizerResult.luisResult);
            break;
        case 'q_sample-qna':
            await this.processSampleQnA(context);
            break;
        default:
            this.logger.log(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
            await context.sendActivity(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
            break;
        }
    }

}

module.exports.DispatchBot = DispatchBot;
```

Error -

```
class DispatchBot extends ActivityHandler {
                          ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

So what is the way to avoid this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got solved by just uninstalling `botbuilder` package and reinstalling it.